# Use php to caapture POST request aand display on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

php:

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

while(true){
    echo "event: ping\n";
    echo 'data: testtext';
    echo "\n\n";
// Send a simple message at random intervals.
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<h1>PHP SSE demo</h1>

<div id="output"></div>

<script>
  var eventSource = new EventSource("sse.php");
  
  eventSource.addEventListener("ping", (event) => {
      const output = document.getElementById("output");
      output.innerHTML+= event.data;
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to chanage the while loop to `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST'){}`, does it mean I can capture all post request and change it on the webpage?
If i use python requests lib to create a http request ,can I display sent content on webpage,am I going in a right direction or i am understanding something wrong.

Comment: try `addEventListener("message"` instead of ping

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923160/server-sent-events-while-loop-takes-so-much-time-for-page-load-when-page-is-ref